# Is it possible to write to clipboard with `print` in Python?

Tags: python, file, io, clipboard

I always make these bash commands to adjust files where I have to either: (1) copy from stdout; or (2) create a file to copy from that I will never use again.

**Is it possible to use some type of file object that actually dumps the output into the clipboard?**

```
# In Python
with someclipboardfileobject as f:
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, file=f)

# Open up TextEdit
# Paste
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: On a Mac, you could do `$ python file.py > pbcopy`

Comment: pyperclip module?

Comment: in window `python fle.py | clip` @Lev no, you have to pipe, not redirect

Comment: why not save the output to a file, and read the file later in your bash script as needed (your option 2), and then delete the temporary file.

Comment: Why does it have to be a file object?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you're right!

Comment: use `f = io.StringIO()` then dump the whole `f.getvalue()` to the clipboard using whatever method in the dupe link

Comment: @Lev and I don't even _have_ a mac :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I'll be honest here, I'm on Ubuntu right now and it's been a year soon that I haven't touched a Mac...busted.

Comment: @Orka this is too broad / sounds like XY problem, and I've closed as a "composite" duplicate. With all the comments and the links you'll be able to sort this out.

Comment: I asked to see if there a file object that one could actually write to instead of using a different API like with pyperclip.  The io.StringIO() looks like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

There is module called pyperclip you can use it

```
import pyperclip

copyText = ''
with open("filename.csv") as f:
    copyText += f.read()

pyperclip.copy(copyText)
spam = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the "file object" part.